# Need help in building a SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT X,Y,Z from ABC;
```

Suppose it produces results like,

```
         X              |    Y   |   Z
------------------------|--------|------
a/b/c/34y3bkfoi         | Data1  | Data2
a/b/c/56egdhdhh         | Data1  | Data2
a/b/c/h5747858i         | Data1  | Data2
a/b/c/657sgsr65         | Data1  | Data2
x/y/z/67dhgg45h         | Data1  | Data2
x/y/z/6hd467ydh         | Data1  | Data2
```

Now I want to group the data of first column only upto 'a/b/c'. I don't care about other stuff.

or simply putting I want DISTINCT has to be applied on particular context '%/%/%/'.

Expected Result:

```
      X     |    Y   |   Z
------------|--------|------
a/b/c/      | Data1  | Data2
x/y/z/      | Data1  | Data2
```

Any Suggestions?.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server, or MySQL, or Oracle... Don't tag random dbms products. Only tag the one you're using.

Comment: With that table data, specify the expected result!

Comment: is there just a/b/c or also a/a/b ect?

Comment: 'a/b/c/' is just an example  I have many different data like that. I need to do something on the produced result.

Comment: You can have multiple values of Y and Z for a given X. You need to choose MAX or some other aggregate from the group. It's just a GROUP BY left(X,6) or whatever.

Comment: FYI, In my case, First column is an URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substr with instr like this:

```
select substr(X, 1, Instr(X, '/', -1) - 1) as X1,  substr(X, Instr(X, '/', -1) + 1) as X2, Y, Z 
from
(select 'a/b/c/35235235' as X, 'Data1' as Y, 'Data2' as Z from dual);
```

output is:

```
 X1    | X2       |  Y  |  Z
------------------------------
'a/b/c'|'35235235'|Data1|Data2
```

then you `group by X1`

Comment: I think , this will do. I will work on it and get back to you

Comment: sure..and check this out->  SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(X,1,INSTR(X,'/',1,3))),Y,Z from ABC;

Comment: Seems fine if you're certain that's third '/' after which you want to cut :) [INSTR doku](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm)

Comment: yeah , i made a case statement to avoid empty strings

Comment: the -1 in instr means 'search from end to start'. That could be easier

Comment: as i told already the actual data is an URI. For instance, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245063/need-help-in-building-a-sql/42245233?noredirect=1#comment71694353_42245233.  I think, you can understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT X,Y,Z from ABC WHERE X LIKE 'a/b/c/%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` and `LEFT`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(X, 6)
       -- Uncomment if you need 2nd and 3rd column as well
       --,Y
       --,Z
FROM ABC
```

Comment: I think you're missing Y and Z y the `SELECT` clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z, t.i,
       LEFT(X, LEN(X) - t.i + 1),
       RIGHT(X, t.i - 1)
FROM ABC
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(X))) AS t(i)
```

To select distinct you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT X, Y, Z, t.i,
           LEFT(X, LEN(X) - t.i + 1) AS l,
           RIGHT(X, t.i - 1) AS r,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(X, LEN(X) - t.i + 1) 
                              ORDER BY X) AS rn
    FROM ABC
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(X))) AS t(i)
)
SELECT 
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.
I got the expected output using,

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(X,1,INSTR(X,'/',1,3))),Y,Z from ABC;
```